# Implement a findFirst() function in abstract Dao class

Tags: kotlin, realm, dao

I'm starting to pick up Kotlin since a few days.
Atm I am trying to write an abstract Dao class with common functions (copyOrUpdate, delete, ...), but I'm stuck on findFirst & findAll.
My database is Realm.

This is a piece of my Dao:

```
    abstract class Dao<T : RealmModel>() {

    //Get Realm Instance
    val db: Realm by lazy {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    }

    //Delete - 1 Object
    fun delete(input: T) {

        if (db.isInTransaction) {
            input.deleteFromRealm()
        } else {
            db.executeTransaction { realm -> input.deleteFromRealm() }
        }
    }
}
```

I am struggling to add a findFirst() function. I'm not sure if this is possible. Here is a non-working piece of struggle:

```
//Get First
fun findFirst(classType: T): T {

    return db.where(T::class.java)
        .findFirst()
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?
At the moment this function is in my UserDao class.

```
class UserDao() : Dao<User>() {    
   //where
    private fun where(): RealmQuery<User> {
        return db.where<User>()
    }

    // Find First
    fun findFirst(): User? {
        return where()
            .findFirst()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with extension + inline fun

```
inline fun <reified T : RealmModel> Realm.findFirst(): T? {
    return where(T::class.java).findFirst()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `Class<T>` into the constructor:

```
abstract class Dao<T : RealmModel>(private val cls: Class<T>) {    
    fun findFirst(): T? {
        return db.where(cls).findFirst()
    }
}

class UserDao() : Dao<User>(User::class.java) { ... }
```

Kotlin's [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) allow you to avoid or hide it in some circumstances, but not with abstract classes.